# Can a RichFaces toolTip be made to overflow outside enclosing extendedDataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tooltip, css

The RichFaces extended data table, when rendered, has an outer div which sets all overflow to be hidden. Thus, displaying a tooltip per row doesn't work nicely as the tooltip is partially hidden from view when hovering over the row at the bottom or the right edge of the table.

The rendered HTML looks much like this. To be clear, the RichFaces rendering engine is in complete control of outputting the outer DIV's style including "overflow:hidden" on line 3:

```
<div id="toplevelform:myTable" class="extdt-maindiv rich-extdt-maindiv">
    <div id="toplevelform:myTable:od" class="extdt-outerdiv"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">

        <!-- inner divs to display rows and columns with their 
            respective tooltips here -->

    </div>
</div>
```

The "overflow:hidden" on line 3 is what causes the problem and if I manually remove it using a client-side postfix (e.g. Firebug editor) it fixes the problem, but I need to solve it within the RichFaces framework so that CSS is never outputed in the first place.

The RichFaces markup used to produce this looks much like this:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="myTable" value="#{backingBean.myIterableProperty}" var="myPropVar">
    <rich:column id="nameCol" width="100%">
        <h:outputText value="#{myPropVar.name}"/>
        <rich:toolTip direction="bottom-right" layout="block">
            My tooltip text here...
        </rich:toolTip>
    </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

Is there a clean way to have the tooltips displayed clearly without being restricted to their bounding DIV, given the constraint that it must be fixed before it gets to the client?

Altering the tooltip direction is not an answer either, BTW!

Comment: I guess you would have better answer opportunities by providing the generated HTML code in a question that only involves CSS and CSS-overflow

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, I have already provided the generated HTML code. Also, I understand how to deal with CSS overflow in a manual HTML situation so an answer to that alone is not enough to deal with the question.

Comment: Well, JSF/RichFaces will generate plain HTML in the end, so you can try to solve the problem there and then apply it in your Facelets code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I already have, by removing the overflow:hidden CSS in line 3 (by simply using Firebug). Perhaps I didn't convey this very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. In this way, the RichFaces extended data table is annoyingly defective.